# ¿Como filtrar un SpatialPolygonDataFrame con un dataframe?

Tags: r

Tengo un SpatialPolygonsDataFrame con su respectivo índice y de tamaño "n", y tengo un dataframe de tamaño "m" solo con los índices escogidos después de un muestreo aleatorio. ¿Como puedo hacer la selección en el SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Ejemplo:

SpatialPolygonsDataFrame:

```
   edad tiempo sexo
1    22  14.21    M
2    34  10.36    H
3    29  11.89    H
4    25  13.81    M
5    30  12.03    M
6    33  10.99    H
7    31  12.48    M
8    27  13.37    M
9    25  12.29    H
10   25  11.92    H
```

dataframe:

```
  idx
1   3
2   7
3   9
```

Y el resultado que espero es:

```
  edad tiempo sexo
1   29  11.89    H
2   31  12.48    M
3   25  12.29    H
```

Este es obviamente un ejemplo, ya que tengo varios miles de registros.
Estoy trabajando en R

Gracias

Comment: Hola @dlmorac, bienvenido. ¿Lo que quieres hacer filtrar un data.frame (en este caso no habría nada específico del SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, al menos no en tu ejemplo) a partir de otro que contiene los número de índice de las filas que te interesan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo el resultado esperado en tu ejemplo lo que quieres hacer es un subconjunto de un data.frame usando los número de índice de filas que están en otros. Es es muy fácil si extraes esos números de índice como un vector (eso lo haremos con `$`) y lo pasas a una función que haga subconjuntos, como `[` (que casi siempre se usa como `[ , ]` o `dplyr::slice()`

```
library(tidyverse) #Para tribble() y slice()
tribble(~edad,~tiempo, ~sexo,
          22,  14.21,    "M",
          34,  10.36,    "H",
          29,  11.89,    "H",
          25,  13.81,    "M",
          30,  12.03,    "M",
          33,  10.99,    "H",
          31,  12.48,    "M",
          27,  13.37,    "M",
          25,  12.29,    "H",
          25,  11.92,    "H") -> df_datos

tribble(~idx, 
           3, 
           7, 
           9) -> df_filtro

df_datos %>% 
  slice(df_filtro$idx)    #dplyr

df_datos[df_filtro$idx, ]  #R base
```

No debería ser diferente para un SpatialPolygonsDataFrame si lo usas sobre la parte `data`.

De todos modo si te interesa trabajar con objetos cartográficos dentro de un data.frame y hacer las operaciones convencionales de un data.frame para manipulación de datos te sugiero que investigues sobre la librería (y clase) `sf`, por ejemplo en https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html Con ella he reemplazado a los SPDF, es mucho más simple de manejar y se puede hacer lo mismo o más que con SPDF.

Comment: Ya hice este ejercicio con dos dataframes y no tuve problemas, la cuestión es que a la hora de hacer el mismo proceso con el SpatialPolygonsDataFrame hay un error con las clases, por lo cual debo convertir el SpatialPolygonsDataFrame a dataframe y en este paso pierdo el componente espacial.

Comment: Volví a hacer el ejercicio y me funcionó la forma base de R (con [ ]).

Comment: Que bueno! Seguramente la clase `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` tiene un método para `[` y `slice()` no. Para usar `slice` debería usar datos en formato `sf`, si es que te interesa.

Comment: Una pregunta, estoy haciendo la selección opuesta, es decir, deseo obtener los datos restantes de la selección anterior. ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: `df_datos[-df_filtro$idx, ]` El signo `-` inmediatamente a la izquierda del vector indica que esos índices se eliminan.